# How do I get started integrating Git with Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea

I've set up a Git server on my LAN (Simple Git Server for Mac). I'm using other machines on the LAN for Android Studio development. What now? On Android Studio's VCS menu, "Integrate Project..." is grayed out.

If I understand, I have to first create a local repository on the workstations, then somehow get my project files into it and get it copied to the server. Can't figure out how to do either. It seems usable if you already have your remote repository set up and populated, but I can't get to square one.

Also: is it recommended to have a separate repository for each project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a git repository set up online. First you do `git init` in the directory that you want to submit to git, then you need to commit the files you want to add by doing `git add .` for all your files or `git add <your file>` for a specific file. After that you need to commit the files by doing `git commit -m "your message here "` and then you do:

```
git remote add origin <remote repository URL> //get this from git assuming your have already set up the git repo
# Sets the new remote
git remote -v
# Verifies the new remote URL
Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.

git push -u origin master
# Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin
```

All this info comes from the git documentation here: 
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

And yes, typically you want to have a separate repository for each project. There are exceptions, but personally, I have yet to find a suitable one.

Comment: Thanks. I guess when IntelliJ says they have "integrated" git, they're exaggerating a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it helps. Feel free to upvote if you like the answer :)

Comment: IntelliJ does have integration with Git. Check the VCS menu. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/version-control-with-intellij-idea.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/enabling-version-control.html

Comment: @RobertLewis  they have integration, but you are responsible for setting up the repo locally on your machine. Once that is setup IntelliJ has the ability to interface with the VCS.